# WLAN connection breaks after ~ 1 minute

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.04

My computer uses ethernet for some years; now I wanted to use WiFi and bought an USB dongle.

The dongle worked out-of-the-box, but the connection keeps only for about a minute. After that internet is gone and I cannot see any SSID anymore.

I can use the dongle again for a minute by removing it and plugging it in again. But one minute is way too short to use it that way...

I switched off USB power management (I think) by adding

```
USB_BLACKLIST="0bda:818b"
```

to /etc/default/tlp but that didn't help.

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
```

lsmod:

```
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
mac80211              819200  1 rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              688128  2 mac80211
```

Ubuntu version is 19.04 with latest updates. Kernel is 5.0.0-32-generic.

Syslog tells me:

```
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420307] usb 1-7: Unhandled C2H event 54 seq 0e
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420348] C2H content: 30 77 1b 2a 1a 30 d2 bf 39 28 7f 27 c9 64 9e 2c
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420353] C2H content: d4 30 be 5d 39 7f 6d 3e 28 af 1c 9b 23 06 4c a3
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420358] C2H content: 3b 07 2f 72 bd 7c 1a c9 24 76 1b f3 64 f4 83 f0
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420361] C2H content: 7b d2 82 56 c5 a6 16 b3 4c 5b f7 2a 0d 6f 70 b9
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420364] C2H content: 8e 43 d4 ad ce f4 47 a3 07 db 7d 42 0f d1 30 6a
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420368] C2H content: 21 9e 8d 79 1d 4b 51 e6 bb aa 5a 62 f6 a5 7a 75
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420371] C2H content: 86 16 17 3a 51 6c af 62 e7 8c b3 5c 18 1f 48 da
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420374] C2H content: 38 01 3b 05 28 28 ba 7c 3d d7 75 d6 f6 8f 92 85
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420377] C2H content: aa 2b 92 b6 99 ad ac 56 fc 48 9d 99 ff ad ac 56
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420381] C2H content: fc 99 ff 5e 40 49 af b2 2e 56 dc 1f 39 28 84 1e
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420384] C2H content: ae 71 34 fb bd d3 1c 09 8a db 69 fe e8 43 73 20
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420387] C2H content: a4 63 07 f9 23 a7 7e 8c da 96 61 d7 7a 96 22 15
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420390] C2H content: b9 bf 10 68 e4 74 cc 93 a8 cb 30 48 2a 2b 73 d7
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420393] C2H content: d8 e0 90 64 22 aa 12 de 6d 4c 47 ea 3f 94 17 86
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420397] C2H content: 0b 01 ae 58 9a 5f a6 f1 a7 ed f2 63 a1 5a 36 57
Nov  1 14:25:50 home kernel: [  313.420400] C2H content: f7 29 7f c2 4a
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187955] usb 1-7: Unhandled C2H event 5b seq bd
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187983] C2H content: 52 92 58 dd 04 b4 45 dd 2a c5 d6 52 d5 1b 5b cf
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187988] C2H content: 2f 55 55 0b 88 9b c5 5c fd bf 3b 11 98 9a 7b 3a
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187991] C2H content: 12 dd cd 81 b4 fb d3 89 00 4c 4d b8 e4 bb 4e 8d
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187995] C2H content: 5f ad 2d ea 78 f9 01 1c 4f bb 0c ca a3 5a bf 7c
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.187999] C2H content: d8 a1 b4 ec 76 50 eb 12 a7 41 d0 21 47 48 0b 35
Nov  1 14:25:51 home kernel: [  314.188002] C2H content: 93 e4 5d ba b4 94 d8 10
Nov  1 14:25:54 home kernel: [  317.234125] usb 1-7: Unhandled C2H event a5 seq 49
Nov  1 14:25:54 home kernel: [  317.234129] C2H content: 3d 94 1e 09 1b c3 08 e7 df 97 4d 64 4f e9 0c 6e
Nov  1 14:25:54 home kernel: [  317.234130] C2H content: 83 17 63 f5 d3 65 c1 dd 70 5a f2 48 c6 da 9e 12
Nov  1 14:25:54 home kernel: [  317.234131] C2H content: 49 73 95 48 71 82 eb 74 8b 6a df b6 67 ce 57 32
Nov  1 14:25:54 home kernel: [  317.234132] C2H content: d7 c1 51 a4 cb 7e ef e9 bd e8 3f
Nov  1 14:25:54 home wpa_supplicant[992]: wlx0013ef30306d: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Nov  1 14:25:54 home NetworkManager[993]: <warn>  [1572614754.9218] sup-iface[0x558cd4dd63d0,wlx0013ef30306d]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Nov  1 14:25:54 home wpa_supplicant[992]: wlx0013ef30306d: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov  1 14:25:54 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614754.9297] device (wlx0013ef30306d): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Nov  1 14:25:55 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614755.0266] device (wlx0013ef30306d): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov  1 14:25:56 home wpa_supplicant[992]: wlx0013ef30306d: SME: Trying to authenticate with a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 (SSID='o2-WLAN85' freq=2437 MHz)
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.931911] wlx0013ef30306d: authenticate with a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.960784] wlx0013ef30306d: send auth to a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 (try 1/3)
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.962818] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.962831] Rate marked as an HT rate but passed status->rate_idx is not an MCS index [0-76]: 102 (0x66)
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963041] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at net/mac80211/rx.c:4547 ieee80211_rx_napi+0x74b/0xad0 [mac80211]
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963044] Modules linked in: ccm vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci arc4 binfmt_misc rtl8xxxu mac80211 cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel ccp snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm irqbypass snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi wmi_bmof snd_seq snd_seq_device input_leds snd_timer serio_raw k8temp snd soundcore mac_hid nvidia_uvm(POE) sch_fq_codel cuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops firewire_ohci firewire_core pata_acpi crc_itu_t drm r8169 ahci libahci realtek i2c_piix4 ipmi_devintf pata_atiixp ipmi_msghandler wmi floppy
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963114] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P           OE     5.0.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963116] Hardware name:  /GA-MA790X-DS4, BIOS F9 08/12/2009
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963198] RIP: 0010:ieee80211_rx_napi+0x74b/0xad0 [mac80211]
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963204] Code: e9 d7 fc ff ff 48 c7 85 38 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 80 f9 4c 0f 86 c8 f9 ff ff 0f b6 f1 48 c7 c7 20 f1 50 c1 89 f2 e8 37 e9 1d d3 <0f> 0b e9 ab fc ff ff 48 8b b5 58 ff ff ff 48 85 f6 0f 84 2b 01 00
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963206] RSP: 0018:ffff8d99cba03de8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963210] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8d99c7225d00 RCX: 0000000000000000
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963212] RDX: 0000000000040400 RSI: 00000000000000f6 RDI: 0000000000000300
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963214] RBP: ffff8d99cba03eb8 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000000004bd
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963216] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8d99c267c7a0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963219] R13: ffffffffc150d648 R14: ffff8d99c267cca8 R15: 0000000000000001
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963222] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8d99cba00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963224] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963226] CR2: 00007f368c02a028 CR3: 0000000141e50000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963229] Call Trace:
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963233]  <IRQ>
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963252]  ? rtl8xxxu_queue_rx_urb+0x68/0xc0 [rtl8xxxu]
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963261]  ? rtl8xxxu_rx_complete+0x6b/0xc0 [rtl8xxxu]
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963336]  ieee80211_tasklet_handler+0xc4/0xd0 [mac80211]
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963348]  tasklet_action_common.isra.21+0x5f/0x110
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963353]  tasklet_action+0x22/0x30
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963360]  __do_softirq+0xdc/0x2f3
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963366]  irq_exit+0xc0/0xd0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963370]  do_IRQ+0x84/0xe0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963375]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963376]  </IRQ>
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963381] RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0x12/0x20
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963384] Code: 48 02 20 48 8b 00 a8 08 75 c3 e9 7c ff ff ff 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 55 48 89 e5 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d e2 ef 5c 00 fb f4 <5d> c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 55 48 89 e5 e9 07 00 00
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963386] RSP: 0018:ffffffff95c03df8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffde
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963390] RAX: 0001ad4000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000001
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963392] RDX: 00000000000b93d2 RSI: 0000000000000083 RDI: 0000000000000000
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963394] RBP: ffffffff95c03df8 R08: ffff8d99cba1d060 R09: ffff98a640da3a28
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963396] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000000
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963398] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963410]  default_idle+0x22/0x150
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963417]  amd_e400_idle+0x42/0x50
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963421]  arch_cpu_idle+0x15/0x20
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963425]  default_idle_call+0x2c/0x30
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963430]  do_idle+0x1f8/0x280
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963435]  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963440]  rest_init+0xae/0xb0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963448]  arch_call_rest_init+0xe/0x1b
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963453]  start_kernel+0x4f5/0x516
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963458]  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x26
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963463]  x86_64_start_kernel+0x74/0x77
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963468]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  318.963474] ---[ end trace 468488740ff8eb2d ]---
Nov  1 14:25:56 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614756.2167] device (wlx0013ef30306d): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.162344] wlx0013ef30306d: send auth to a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 (try 2/3)
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.366346] wlx0013ef30306d: send auth to a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 (try 3/3)
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367884] usb 1-7: Unhandled C2H event e5 seq e9
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367914] C2H content: 0c 5a ff 96 4a 2e 3f a0 9f fe ff 96 9f fe 8d d1
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367919] C2H content: 30 89 c0 00 00 00 64 00 11 04 00 09 6f 32 2d 57
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367923] C2H content: 4c 41 4e 38 35 01 08 82 84 8b 96 24 30 48 6c 03
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367926] C2H content: 01 06 05 04 00 01 00 00 2a 01 04 2f 01 04 30 14
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.367929] C2H content: 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01
Nov  1 14:25:56 home kernel: [  319.570327] wlx0013ef30306d: authentication with a0:e4:cb:a5:4c:10 timed out
Nov  1 14:25:56 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614756.8509] device (wlx0013ef30306d): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Nov  1 14:25:57 home NetworkManager[993]: <warn>  [1572614757.2477] dhcp6 (wlx0013ef30306d): request timed out
Nov  1 14:25:57 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614757.2478] dhcp6 (wlx0013ef30306d): state changed unknown -> timeout
Nov  1 14:25:57 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614757.2497] dhcp6 (wlx0013ef30306d): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 7401
Nov  1 14:25:57 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614757.2498] dhcp6 (wlx0013ef30306d): state changed timeout -> done
Nov  1 14:25:57 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614757.3518] device (wlx0013ef30306d): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov  1 14:26:10 home NetworkManager[993]: <warn>  [1572614770.2478] device (wlx0013ef30306d): link timed out.
Nov  1 14:26:10 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614770.2499] device (wlx0013ef30306d): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  1 14:26:10 home NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1572614770.2559] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov  1 14:26:10 home whoopsie[4358]: [14:26:10] offline
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it will solve he problem but maybe you can try to replace the driver by this driver: 
https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

Here, you can find a more detailed procedure: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html#ID9

Here, commands that you will need to enter:
First, you install all packages required for the installation of the driver using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Now you can clone the git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux.git
```

Move to the new folder created:

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux
```

Remove current drivers (check with `dkms status` or `sudo lshw -C network` what drivers are available):

```
sudo rmmod rtl8xxxu
```

As mentionned by @chili555, you blacklisted the current driver:

```
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" >> ./blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf
sudo mv ./blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

And  finally you can install the driver:

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

You reboot or you load the driver by doing `sudo modprobe 8192eu`
And everything should work now !

Comment: And if you do that, and I recommend that you do, you will need to blacklist the conflicting driver rtl8xxxu. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, you're right. It is described in the readme of the github link

Comment: You should post the commands necessary to install as link only answers are frowned upon.  I am not sure why the person that does the easylinuxtips installs dkms but doesn't actually use it and that will require a user to reinstall after every kernel update

Comment: @Jeremy31, thanks for your advice, I'm quite new and did not want to take credit for something that I didn't do. Regarding dkms, I'm not sure to understand your question because in both github and easylinuxtips, they are using dkms for installing the driver.